# AngularJs datatable dynamic table change

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatables

I am working on a project and i want to do some things which are new to me. I am new in AngularJS and newer in angular data tables.

I got angular data table from [**here**](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome) and is a little bit tricky for me because i don't really know how to use it. Examples are not very explanatory for me.

What i want to do:

- i have a sigle page with some checkboxes on the left
- on the right i want a data table with data provided by server after user clicks on a checkbox
- data table must change dinamicaly because depends on the request i have other headers for data table. For example when user click on "role" objects returned have only 2 fields id and role, i want to render role column but not id. When user clicks on "users" data returned by server has multiple objects which have much more fields, for example : "accNonExp", "accNonLocked", "email", "username" and others.

How can i do this ?

here is my conde right now :

js :

```
depo.controller('masterMainController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.listOfTables = null;
    $scope.tableData = {};

    $scope.onClick = function(){
        $scope.tableData = getTableData($scope.valueSelected);
    };

    $http.post('/master/listOfTables').success(function (response) {
        $scope.listOfTables = response;
        console.log(response);
    });

    function getTableData(table) {
        $http.post('/master/tableData/' + table).success(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            return response;
        });
    }

    $scope.dataTable = function(DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromJson($scope.tableData)
            .withPaginationType('full_numbers');
/*        vm.dtColumns = [
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('ID'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('firstName').withTitle('First name'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('lastName').withTitle('Last name').notVisible()
        ];*/
    }
}]);
```

JSP:

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/includes/onlyForLoggedUsers.jsp" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Main Master</title>
</head>
<script content="text/javascript" src="/res/custom_script/admin/masterMain.js"></script>
<body ng-app="depo">
<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="masterMainController">
    <p class="logout_paragraph">Logged as <strong>${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name}</strong> | <a
            id="logout_link" onclick="formSubmit()">Logout</a></p>

    <form action="/logout" method="post" id="logoutForm" style="display: none;">
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
    </form>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h2>Welcome !</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="divChkListOfTables" class="admin_left_menu pre-scrollable col-md-2">
            <div id="chkListOfTables" class="admin_tables_list radio">
                <h4>Tables</h4>
                <label ng-repeat="table in listOfTables.tables" class="admin_tables_list_chk_box">
                    <input type="radio" name="chkTablesRadio" ng-model="$parent.valueSelected" ng-change="onClick()"
                           ng-value="table" class="radio-button"> {{table}}
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="admin_data_table" class="col-md-10">
            <table datatable="dataTable" dt-options="masterMainController.dtOptions" dt-columns="masterMainController.dtColumns" class="row-border hover">

            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Spring RestController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/master")
public class MasterMainRest {

    @Autowired
    UnitService unitService;

    @Autowired
    RoleService roleService;

    @Autowired
    UsersService usersService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/listOfTables", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public MasterTablesDTO getListOfTables(){
        List<String> tables = new ArrayList<>();
        tables.add("unit");
        tables.add("role");
        tables.add("users");

        MasterTablesDTO masterTablesDTO = new MasterTablesDTO();
        masterTablesDTO.setTables(tables);

        return masterTablesDTO;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/tableData/{table}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public List getTablesData(@PathVariable String table){
        List list = null;
        switch (table){
            case "unit":
                list = unitService.findAll();
                break;
            case "role":
                list = roleService.findAll();
                break;
            case "users":
                list = usersService.findAll();
                break;
        }
        return list;
    }

}
```

When i reach this page i gat this error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined
    at U (jquery.dataTables.min.js:63)
    at xa (jquery.dataTables.min.js:67)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:91)
    at Function.n.extend.each (jquery-2.1.3.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.n.each (jquery-2.1.3.min.js:2)
    at m [as dataTable] (jquery.dataTables.min.js:83)
    at h.fn.DataTable (jquery.dataTables.min.js:159)
    at Object.g [as renderDataTableAndEmitEvent] (angular-datatables.min.js:6)
    at Object.h [as doRenderDataTable] (angular-datatables.min.js:6)
    at Object.d.render (angular-datatables.min.js:6)
```

Yes i know this error is beause $scope.tableData is empty, or this is what i read on some forums.
How can i make first checkbox checked and $scope.tableData loaded with data acording to that checkbox checked ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Since the getTableData(table) function isn't returning any value $scope.tableData is undefined as you mentioned. This is because of the AJAX request being asynchronous.

To fix this you have to supply a callback to the $http success where you fill the $scope.tableData. To learn more about promises checkout angulars documentation for the q implementation:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Something like this should fix it.

```
$scope.onClick = function(){
    getTableData($scope.valueSelected).success(function(response) {
        $scope.tableData = response.data 
    });
};

function getTableData(table) {
    return $http.post('/master/tableData/' + table);
}
```

Comment: in my conde, onClick is returning data when i click on one of those checkboxes

Comment: Sure, but in the code you have supplied your not setting the $scope.tableData correctly. As I mentioned the $http.post method doesn't return any data but a promise that contains a success method. In my example you can see that I am setting the $scope.tableData inside a callback that I am passing to that success method.